# Selecting Third-tier ActiveRecord_Relation - Rails, ActiveRecord, HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models. `User`, `Message` and `Filter`, with the relations shown below. How can I select `User.find(*).filters.messages`?

**User:**

- `has_many :filters`
- `has_and_belongs_to_many :messages`

**Message:**

- `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`
- `has_and_belongs_to_many :filters`

**Filter:**

- `belongs_to :user`
- `has_and_belongs_to_many :messages`

## EDIT 1:

I am assigning the result to an instance variable called `@filtered_messages` and want to iterate through it in my view.

Here is my action:

```
...
def show
  @filtered_messages = ...
end
...
```

Here is my view partial (summary):

```
<% @filtered_messages.each do |message| %>
...
  <%= message.author%> #author is a column in messages_tables
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get all of the messages for all of the filters of one user. Is that right? Try this:

`User.find(*).filters.includes(:messages).map { |filter| filter.messages }.flatten`

Comment: I am trying to assign this to an instance variable called `@filtered_messages` and then iterate through it in my view. While this solution does return the collection I want in the console, I get the `undefined method `...' for #<Message::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:....>`  in my view.

Comment: Try @evanbikes' answer above. If that doesn't work, can you post the code you are using to iterate in the view?

Comment: If you want to use this in the view, you'll have to add `.flatten` on the end.

Comment: ^^ Can you explain that?

Comment: What you're getting is actually an array of Relations, not filters. It's like an array of arrays but the arrays are Relations. So then flattening returns just a plain old array of messages. So this will work, but will be doing the work in Ruby, not SQL. Which isn't *terrible*, just usually a little slower. But you should probably do this: `User.find(*).messages.includes(:filters).map { |message| message.filters }.flatten` to speed it up.

Comment: @sixty4bit ok, it must be something in my iteration. I'm getting undefined method `...' for #<Filter>. I'm going to update the OP with my views and actions.

Comment: @Dimitry_N I think what you want is actually the reverse of this. So swap all the messages and filters and it should return an array of filtered messages.

Comment: Sure! I swapped messages/filters per evanbikes' advice

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
class User
  has_many :filters
  has_and_belongs_to_many :messages
  has_many :filter_messages, through: :filters, class_name: 'Message'
end
```

And then `@user.filter_messages` should return what you want.

Comment: getting a NoMethod  - `undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Where are you getting that? On Rails start? Or in the views? Or in the console?

Comment: in my `users_controller`, when assigning to @filtered_messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.find(1).filters.first.messages
```

Comment: this would work, but I have more than one `filter` for each `user`, and need to select all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Message.joins(:filters).where(filters {user_id: user_id})
```

But replace `user_id` with however you determine your User's id in your app.